# how to use key in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to search value in `xml` using `key` but I am not getting expected result
here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyZ/1

```
  <xsl:key name="mid" match="parent_id" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
    <xsl:variable name="msid" select="'54'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="msids_map">
        <parent_id id="34">
          <childid>1</childid>
          <childid>2</childid>
        </parent_id>
        <parent_id id="54">
          <childid>3</childid>
          <childid>4</childid>
        </parent_id>
    </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name ="abc" select="ext:node-set(msids_map)">
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="getValue" select=
        "key('mid', $abc)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$getValue"/>
```

**Expected output**

```
<parent_id id="54">
              <childid>3</childid>
              <childid>4</childid>
            </parent_id>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few minor *syntax* issues, and a major *context* issue. Keys operates in the context of the current document - which in your example is the input XML document. In order to get the key to operate on the variable (which is a document of its own), you must first switch the context - for example, by using `xsl:for-each select="$abc"`before calling the key.

Here is a full example (with the syntax errors corrected, too):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="mid" match="parent_id" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <hmtl>
        <xsl:variable name="msid" select="'54'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="msids_map">
            <parent_id id="34">
                <childid>1</childid>
                <childid>2</childid>
            </parent_id>
            <parent_id id="54">
                <childid>3</childid>
                <childid>4</childid>
            </parent_id>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name ="abc" select="ext:node-set($msids_map)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$abc">
            <xsl:variable name="getValue" select="key('mid', $msid)"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$getValue"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </hmtl>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyZ/4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as edited in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

        <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:key name="mid" match="parent_id" use="@id"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
          <hmtl>
        <xsl:variable name="msid" select="'54'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="msids_map">
            <parent_id id="34">
              <childid>1</childid>
              <childid>2</childid>
            </parent_id>
            <parent_id id="54">
              <childid>3</childid>
              <childid>4</childid>
            </parent_id>
        </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name ="abc" select="$msids_map" as="node()">
           </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$abc/key('mid', $msid)"/>
          </hmtl>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

**output**

```
   <parent_id id="54">
      <childid>3</childid>
      <childid>4</childid>
   </parent_id>
```

Comment: Your solution requires XSLT 2.0 The question is tagged XSLT 1.0.

Comment: actually i didn't run this code in my editor, only run at the location provided in question, so that happened, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The key function in 1.0 works on the context node.  So, to use a key on a variable you have to somehow get it to be the context node.  Another approach suitable for 1.0 would be to not use keys at all.  Just use the variable and filter for what you want.  Is there some pressing reason for you to use keys?  Are you looking for uniqueness?  That can be done with a filter too.

```
 <!-- Add $ before variable to fix bug. -->
  <xsl:variable name ="abc" select="msxsl:node-set($msids_map)">

     .....

  <xsl:variable name="getValue">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$abc/parent_id[@id=$msid]"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```